# Rails: how to initialize child records fetched with `where` with same parent instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have `has_many` relation like this:

```
class User
  has_many      :jobs, -> { order("flow_jobs.id desc") }, :class_name => "UserJob"
end
class Job
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I have a query `jobs = user.jobs.where(...)` which returns collection of jobs belonging to the same user. They all however have their own not shared instance of User AR object. How can  I avoid it and have them initialized with the same `user` instance I use for query?

```
> jobs = user.jobs.where(id: [1092, 1090])
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [....]
> jobs[0].user.object_id == jobs[1].user.object_id
 => false 
> jobs[0].user.object_id == user.object_id
 => false
```

Comment: I didn't get your question. can you give an example?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I added more code to explain. user object is different between jobs and not equals original user object

Comment: Ok, It seems I got it. You mean to have same user object in _memory_. Look [inverse_of](https://makandracards.com/makandra/12331-always-use-inverse_of-to-connect-two-models-in-a-belongs_to-has_many-relationship) option and use it.